# Azure solr server error

Tags: azure, solr, remote-access, remote-server, solrcloud

I have virtual machine with windows 7 and Sorl 5.0 on it.
I want to have access to it from remote computer, so I can access solr admin panel from internet.

**If:**

```
<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host"/></Set>
```

Localhost and INTERNAL IP ADDRESS is working on my remote pc.

**If:**
`<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="INTERNAL IP` ADDRESS"/>
INTERNAL IP ADDRESS is working on my remote pc.

**If:**

```
<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS"/></Set>
```

Doesn't work at all throws error when starting server(**java -jar start.jar**):

```
FAILED SelectChannelConnector@host.address:8983: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
WARN  - 2015-04-21 11:07:01.013; [   ] org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle; FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@41e625ff: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

Maybe It is wrong way, could you tell me what is right way, thanks a lot for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with opening local port and accessing Solr host by this port. So I get access to local Solr server through opened port. Use for it windows firewall.